# Problems with long threeparttable table

Tags: longtable, threeparttable, threeparttablex

I am a new user of LaTeX and trying to create a long three-part table, that would fit across 2 pieces of portrait a4 paper, and getting myself in a muddle. I managed to get it to fit on a page widthwise but can't see how to get it to split lengthways properly with the table notes, and get it to centre properly - unfortunately i have to keep it in 12pt font as its a requirement for my dissertation.

I've put my current code and a picture of the output below. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you and hope you are having a good day :) Emma

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, doublespacing, nolistspacing, chapterinoneline, parskip, liststotoc] {article}

    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
    \usepackage{fullpage}
    \usepackage[british]{babel} 
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{rotating}
    \usepackage{mathtools}
    \usepackage{natbib}
    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \usepackage{mathpazo} % font
    \usepackage{pdflscape}
    \usepackage{cmbright}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{adjustbox}
    \usepackage{caption}
    \usepackage{tabularx}
    \usepackage{array}
    \usepackage{multirow}
    \usepackage{graphics}
    \usepackage[para]{threeparttable}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{longtable,booktabs,threeparttablex}

     \begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \label{tab:Independent variables sum}
    \caption{Independent variables survey questions and response frequencies}

\begin{threeparttablex}

\begin{longtable}{llccc}
    \toprule
    {\textbf{Variable}} & {\textbf{Survey Question}} & \textbf{Response category} & {\textbf{Freq.}} & {\textbf{\%}} \\
    \midrule
    \endfirsthead

    \multicolumn{5}{c}%
{{\tablename\ \thetable{} -- continued from previous page}} \\
\hline {\textbf{Variable}} & {\textbf{Survey Question}} & \textbf{Response category} & {\textbf{Freq.}} &{\textbf{\%}} \\ \hline 
\endhead

\hline \multicolumn{3}{|r|}{{Continued on next page}} \\ \hline
\endfoot

\hline
\endlastfoot

    \multirow{23}[2]{2.2cm}{\textbf{Income\tnote{1}}} & \multirow{23}[4]{8cm}{\textit{"What is your household's approximate total annual income (before taxes)? "}} & <£20,000\footnotemark[A] & 43    & 10.4 \\
          &       & £20,000 - £24,999 & 18    & 4.4 \\
          &       & £25,000-£29,999 & 28    & 6.8 \\
          &       & £30,000-£34,999 & 34    & 8.3 \\
          &       & £35,000-£39,999 & 34    & 8.3 \\
          &       & £40,000-£44,999 & 28    & 6.8 \\
          &       & £45,000-£49,999 & 36    & 8.7 \\
          &       & £50,000-£54,999 & 35    & 8.5 \\
          &       & £55,000-£59,999 & 34    & 8.3 \\
          &       & £60,000-£64,999 & 12    & 2.9 \\
          &       & £65,000-£69,999 & 15    & 3.6 \\
          &       & £70,000-£74,999 & 10    & 2.4 \\
          &       & £75,000-£79,999 & 14    & 3.4 \\
          &       & £80,000-£84,999 & 6     & 1.5 \\
          &       & £85,000-£89,999 & 6     & 1.5 \\
          &       & £90,000-£94,999 & 3     & 0.7 \\
          &       & £95,000-£99,999 & 14    & 3.4 \\
          &       & £100,000-£104,999 & 13    & 3.2 \\
          &       & £105,000-£109,999 & 3     & 0.7 \\
          &       & £110,000-£114,999 & 4     & 1 \\
          &       & £115,000-£119,999 & 1     & 0.2 \\
          &       & £120,000-£124,999 & 2     & 0.5 \\
          &       & >£125,000 & 19    & 4.6 \\
    \midrule
   \multirow{3}[2]{2.2cm}{\textbf{Relative Wealth\tnote{B}}} & \multirow{3}[2]{8cm}{\textit{"Compared to most other households in my local community , I feel as though my household's level of wealth is probably…"}} & Lower & 125 & 30.4 \\
          &       & About the same & 174   & 42.2 \\
          &       & Higher & 113   & 27.4 \\
    \midrule
    \multirow{7}[2]{2.2cm}{\textbf{Work-life Balance }} & \multirow{7}[2]{8cm}{\textit{"On a scale of 1-7, rate your work-life balance" }} & Too little work (1) & 7     & 1.7 \\
          &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{2} & 23    & 5.6 \\
          &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{3} & 27    & 6.6 \\
          &       & Good balance (4) & 159   & 38.6 \\
          &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{5} & 126   & 30.6 \\
          &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{6} & 43    & 10.4 \\
          &       & Too much work (7) & 27    & 6.6 \\
    \midrule
    \multirow{4}[2]{2.2cm}{\textbf{Social Capital }} & \multirow{4}[2]{8cm}{\textit{"How strongly do you identify with your neighbourhood? "}} & Not at all & 20    & 4.9 \\
          &       & Not very strongly & 168   & 40.8 \\
          &       & Somewhat strongly & 184   & 44.7 \\
          &       & Very strongly & 40    & 9.7 \\
    \midrule
    \multirow{2}[2]{2.2cm}{\textbf{Injunctive Norm\tnote{C}}} & \multirow{2}[2]{8cm}{\textit{"Most people in my community  think that recycling is something that one ought to do"}} & Disagree/neutral  & 134   & 32.5 \\
          &       & Agree & 278   & 67.5 \\
    \midrule
    \multirow{2}[2]{2.2cm}{\textbf{Descriptive Norm}} & \multirow{2}[2]{8cm}{\textit{"I think over 50\% of my community engage in recycling" }} & Disagree/neutral  & 130   & 31.6 \\
          &       & Agree & 282   & 68.4 \\
    \midrule
    \multirow{2}[2]{2.2cm}{\textbf{Personal Norm\tnote{C}}} & \multirow{2}[2]{8cm}{\textit{"I  think that recycling is something that one ought to do"}} & Disagree/neutral  & 37    & 9 \\
          &       & Agree & 375 & 91\\
    \bottomrule
    \end{longtable}

         \begin{tablenotes}
        \item [A] Originally there were Income had the categories "<£12,499" and "£12,500-£19,999", but these were collapsed into the "<£20,000" categories so that the ordinal variable had equal jumps between category and could be treated as a continuous variable with £5,000 units. \newline
        \item [B] Originally categories were "much lower", "a little lower", "about the same", "a little higher" and "much higher". Due to low number of responses in the two extremes of this scale, responses were re coded as above. \newline
        \item [C] Originally responses were on a 5 point agree/disagree scale, but due to the low number of responses in some categories these were collapsed into dummy variables, with 0 being the disagrees or neutral, and 1 being agree or strongly agree. 
    \end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttablex}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: Please make your code compilable. Typically `l` and `c` type columns don't accept a width argument.

Comment: To enable mid-table page breaks take a look at the `longtable` package and switch from `threeparttable` to `threeparttablex`.

Comment: Regarding the quite large white spaces in the first two columns of your table: Woud you be open to redesigning some parts?

Comment: Yeah of course! Anything you think that would help, I'm just trying to amend your comments :)

Comment: I have now made it compilable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my suggestion using `longtable` and `threeparttablex`. In order to save some space, I have also changed the layout of the first two columns and in addition added the `siunitx` package to improve the alignment of the numbers in the last two columns:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt] {article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[british]{babel} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{mathpazo} % font
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{cmbright}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{longtable,booktabs,threeparttablex}
\usepackage{siunitx}


\begin{document}
\begin{ThreePartTable}
  \begin{TableNotes}
\item [A1] Originally there were Income had the categories "<£12,499" and "£12,500-£19,999", but these were collapsed into the "<£20,000" categories so that the ordinal variable had equal jumps between category and could be treated as a continuous variable with £5,000 units. \newline
\item [B] Originally categories were "much lower", "a little lower", "about the same", "a little higher" and "much higher". Due to low number of responses in the two extremes of this scale, responses were re coded as above. 
\newline
\item [C] Originally responses were on a 5 point agree/disagree scale, but due to the low number of responses in some categories these were collapsed into dummy variables, with 0 being the disagrees or neutral, and 1 being agree or strongly agree. 
  \end{TableNotes}
   \begin{longtable}{p{8.75cm}lS[table-format=3]S[table-format=2.1]}
    \caption{Independent variables survey questions and response frequencies} \label{tab:Independent variables sum}\\
    \toprule
    {\textbf{Variable} (Survey question)}   & \textbf{Response category} & {\textbf{Freq.}} &{\textbf{\%}} \\
    \midrule
    \endfirsthead
        \caption{Independent variables survey questions and response frequencies - continued}\\
    \toprule
    {\textbf{Variable} (Survey question)}   & \textbf{Response category} & {\textbf{Freq.}} &{\textbf{\%}} \\
    \midrule
    \endhead
  \multicolumn{4}{r}{(\emph{continued on next page})} \\
  \bottomrule
  \endfoot
  \insertTableNotes
\endlastfoot

    \textbf{Income\tnote{1}}  & <£20,000 & 43    & 10.4 \\*
\multirow{2}{=}{\textit{"What is your household's approximate total annual income (before taxes)? "}        }  &        £20,000 - £24,999 & 18    & 4.4 \\*
            & £25,000-£29,999 & 28    & 6.8 \\*
            & £30,000-£34,999 & 34    & 8.3 \\*
            & £35,000-£39,999 & 34    & 8.3 \\*
            & £40,000-£44,999 & 28    & 6.8 \\*
            & £45,000-£49,999 & 36    & 8.7 \\*
            & £50,000-£54,999 & 35    & 8.5 \\*
            & £55,000-£59,999 & 34    & 8.3 \\*
            & £60,000-£64,999 & 12    & 2.9 \\*
            & £65,000-£69,999 & 15    & 3.6 \\*
            & £70,000-£74,999 & 10    & 2.4 \\*
            & £75,000-£79,999 & 14    & 3.4 \\*
            & £80,000-£84,999 & 6     & 1.5 \\*
            & £85,000-£89,999 & 6     & 1.5 \\*
            & £90,000-£94,999 & 3     & 0.7 \\*
            & £95,000-£99,999 & 14    & 3.4 \\*
            & £100,000-£104,999 & 13    & 3.2 \\*
            & £105,000-£109,999 & 3     & 0.7 \\*
            & £110,000-£114,999 & 4     & 1 \\*
            & £115,000-£119,999 & 1     & 0.2 \\*
            & £120,000-£124,999 & 2     & 0.5 \\*
            & >£125,000 & 19    & 4.6 \\
    \midrule
   \textbf{Relative Wealth\tnote{B}} \\*
   \multirow{3}{=}{\textit{"Compared to most other households in my local community , I feel as though my household's level of wealth is probably…"}} 
                 & Lower & 125 & 30.4 \\*
                 & About the same & 174   & 42.2 \\*
                 & Higher & 113   & 27.4 \\
    \midrule
    \textbf{Work-life Balance } \\*
     \textit{"On a scale of 1-7, rate your work-life balance" }
                 & Too little work (1) & 7     & 1.7 \\*
                 & 2 & 23    & 5.6 \\*
                 & 3 & 27    & 6.6 \\*
                 & Good balance (4) & 159   & 38.6 \\*
                 & 5 & 126   & 30.6 \\*
                 & 6 & 43    & 10.4 \\*
                 & Too much work (7) & 27    & 6.6 \\
    \midrule
    \textbf{Social Capital} \\*
     \multirow{2}{=}{\textit{"How strongly do you identify with your neighbourhood? "}}  
          & Not at all & 20    & 4.9 \\*
          & Not very strongly & 168   & 40.8 \\*
          & Somewhat strongly & 184   & 44.7 \\*
          & Very strongly & 40    & 9.7 \\
    \midrule
    \textbf{Injunctive Norm\tnote{C}} \\*
     \multirow{2}{=}{\textit{"Most people in my community  think that recycling is something that one ought to do"}} & Disagree/neutral  & 134   & 32.5 \\*
                 & Agree & 278   & 67.5 \\
    \midrule
    \textbf{Descriptive Norm} \\*
     \multirow{2}{=}{\textit{"I think over 50\% of my community engage in recycling" }} 
          & Disagree/neutral  & 130   & 31.6 \\*
          & Agree & 282   & 68.4 \\
    \midrule
    \textbf{Personal Norm\tnote{C}} \\*
     \multirow{2}{=}{\textit{"I  think that recycling is something that one ought to do"}} 
          & Disagree/neutral  & 37    & 9 \\*
          & Agree & 375 & 91\\
    \bottomrule
    \end{longtable}
\end{ThreePartTable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much this is perfect! You are an actual life saver I've been trying to figure this out all day, thank you again!

Comment: @EmmaClifford: I'm happy I was able to help you. One thing I noticed is that there is a table note called `A1`. In the table you only have a table note mark called `1`. You might want to take a look at that.