# Xltabular, threeparttable across multiple pages

Tags: threeparttable, xltabular

I can't seem to get the table to extend over to the next page with '--continued from previous page' to be at the top of the second page.

Could someone help me how to get this long table over multiple pages with fixed width columns as per my multicolumn code?

Thanks,
Ed

```
\usepackage{tabularx}%,ltablex}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{threeparttablex}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\newcolumntype{b}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{s}{>{\centering\arraybackslash\hsize=.3\hsize}X}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{3cm}}
\newcommand{\heading}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}
\begin{table}[!ht]
\centering
\small

\label{table_pd_idxfut}
\caption{This table outlines the literature around price discovery in Index Futures markets}
\begin{threeparttable}

\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{s|s|s|b}

\toprule

\heading{Study} & \heading{Th./Emp.} & \heading{Metric} & \heading{Key Findings}\\
\midrule\midrule
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{4}{c}{\tablename\ \thetable{} -- continued from previous page} \\\hline
\heading{Study} & \heading{Th./Emp.} & \heading{Metric} & \heading{Key Findings}\\\endhead
\bottomrule
\begin{tablenotes}
\footnotesize
\item \textit{CS} represents \cite{RN124}'s \textit{Component Share}, \textit{IS} represents \cite{RN27}'s \textit{Information Share}, while \textit{ILS} represents \cite{Putni__2013,RN16}'s \textit{Information Leadership Share} metric for measuring price discovery.
\end{tablenotes}
\endfoot
\hline
\endlastfoot


\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{3cm}|}{\cite{Martin_1989}}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{2cm}|}{Empirical}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{1cm}|}{\textit{IS}}& BLAH \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{3cm}|}{\cite{CHUNG_1991}}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{2cm}|}{Empirical}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{1cm}|}{\textit{IS}}& BLAH \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{3cm}|}{\cite{Antoniou_1993}}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{2cm}|}{Empirical}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{1cm}|}{\textit{IS}}& BLAH \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{3cm}|}{\cite{Gr_nbichler_1994}}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{2cm}|}{Empirical}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{1cm}|}{\textit{IS}}& BLAH \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{3cm}|}{\cite{Martikainen_1996}}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{2cm}|}{Empirical}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{1cm}|}{\textit{IS}}& BLAH \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{3cm}|}{\cite{Antoniou_1996}}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{2cm}|}{Empirical}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{1cm}|}{\textit{IS}}& BLAH \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{3cm}|}{\cite{Turkington_1999}}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{2cm}|}{Empirical}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{1cm}|}{\textit{IS}}& BLAH \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{3cm}|}{\cite{Chu_1999}}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{2cm}|}{Empirical}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{1cm}|}{\textit{IS}}& BLAH \\ \hline
% \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{3cm}|}{\cite{Tse_1999}}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{2cm}|}{Empirical}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{1cm}|}{\textit{IS}}& BLAH \\ \hline
% \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{3cm}|}{\cite{Booth_1999}}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{2cm}|}{Empirical}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{1cm}|}{\textit{IS}}& BLAH \\ \hline
% \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{3cm}|}{\cite{Roope_2002}}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{2cm}|}{Empirical}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{1cm}|}{\textit{IS}}& BLAH \\ \hline
% \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{3cm}|}{\cite{Chen_2002}}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{2cm}|}{Empirical}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{1cm}|}{\textit{IS}}& BLAH \\ \hline
% \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{3cm}|}{\cite{Chan_2002}}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{2cm}|}{Empirical}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{1cm}|}{\textit{IS}}& BLAH \\ \hline
% \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{3cm}|}{\cite{Visvikis_2002}}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{2cm}|}{Empirical}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{1cm}|}{\textit{IS}}& BLAH \\ \hline
% \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{3cm}|}{\cite{Lin_2002}}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{2cm}|}{Empirical}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{1cm}|}{\textit{IS}}& BLAH \\ \hline
% \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{3cm}|}{\cite{Frino_2002}}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{2cm}|}{Empirical}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{1cm}|}{\textit{IS}}& BLAH \\ \hline
% \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{3cm}|}{\cite{Karagiannis_2003}}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{2cm}|}{Empirical}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{1cm}|}{\textit{IS}}& BLAH \\ \hline
% \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{3cm}|}{\cite{Frino_2003}}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{2cm}|}{Empirical}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{1cm}|}{\textit{IS}}& BLAH \\ \hline
% \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{3cm}|}{\cite{Chng_2004}}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{2cm}|}{Empirical}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{1cm}|}{\textit{IS}}& BLAH \\ \hline
% \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{3cm}|}{\cite{Cheng_2004}}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{2cm}|}{Empirical}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{1cm}|}{\textit{IS}}& BLAH \\ \hline
% \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{3cm}|}{\cite{Zhong_2004}}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{2cm}|}{Empirical}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{1cm}|}{\textit{IS}}& BLAH \\ \hline
% \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{3cm}|}{\cite{Kurov_2003}}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{2cm}|}{Empirical}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{1cm}|}{\textit{IS}}& BLAH \\ \hline
% \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{3cm}|}{\cite{So_2004}}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{2cm}|}{Empirical}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{1cm}|}{\textit{IS}}& BLAH \\ \hline
% \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{3cm}|}{\cite{Chng_2004}}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{2cm}|}{Empirical}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{1cm}|}{\textit{IS}}& BLAH \\ \hline
% \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{3cm}|}{\cite{Hsieh_2004}}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{2cm}|}{Empirical}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{1cm}|}{\textit{IS}}& BLAH \\ \hline
% \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{3cm}|}{\cite{Ates_2005}}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{2cm}|}{Empirical}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{1cm}|}{\textit{IS}}& BLAH \\ \hline
% \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{3cm}|}{\cite{Spyrou_2005}}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{2cm}|}{Empirical}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{1cm}|}{\textit{IS}}& BLAH \\ \hline
% \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{3cm}|}{\cite{Zhu_2006}}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{2cm}|}{Empirical}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{1cm}|}{\textit{IS}}& BLAH \\ \hline
% \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{3cm}|}{\cite{Nam_2006}}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{2cm}|}{Empirical}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{1cm}|}{\textit{IS}}& BLAH \\ \hline
% \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{3cm}|}{\cite{M__2007}}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{2cm}|}{Empirical}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{1cm}|}{\textit{IS}}& BLAH \\ \hline
% \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{3cm}|}{\cite{Kavussanos_2008}}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{2cm}|}{Empirical}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{1cm}|}{\textit{IS}}& BLAH \\ \hline
% \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{3cm}|}{\cite{Kurov_2008}}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{2cm}|}{Empirical}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{1cm}|}{\textit{IS}}& BLAH \\ \hline
% \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{3cm}|}{\cite{Kurov_2008}}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{2cm}|}{Empirical}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{1cm}|}{\textit{IS}}& BLAH \\ \hline
% \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{3cm}|}{\cite{Floros_2008}}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{2cm}|}{Empirical}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{1cm}|}{\textit{IS}}& BLAH \\ \hline
% \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{3cm}|}{\cite{Hsieh_2008}}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{2cm}|}{Empirical}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{1cm}|}{\textit{IS}}& BLAH \\ \hline
% \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{3cm}|}{\cite{Debasish_2008}}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{2cm}|}{Empirical}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{1cm}|}{\textit{IS}}& BLAH \\ \hline
% \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{3cm}|}{\cite{Swaroop_Debasish_2009}}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{2cm}|}{Empirical}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{1cm}|}{\textit{IS}}& BLAH \\ \hline
% \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{3cm}|}{\cite{Chen_2009}}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{2cm}|}{Empirical}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{1cm}|}{\textit{IS}}& BLAH \\ \hline
% \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{3cm}|}{\cite{Schlusche_2009}}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{2cm}|}{Empirical}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{1cm}|}{\textit{IS}}& BLAH \\ \hline
% \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{3cm}|}{\cite{Tao_2009}}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{2cm}|}{Empirical}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{1cm}|}{\textit{IS}}& BLAH \\ \hline
% \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{3cm}|}{\cite{Varma_2010}}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{2cm}|}{Empirical}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{1cm}|}{\textit{IS}}& BLAH \\ \hline
% \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{3cm}|}{\cite{Wang_2010}}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{2cm}|}{Empirical}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{1cm}|}{\textit{IS}}& BLAH \\ \hline
% \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{3cm}|}{\cite{Jie_Wei_2010}}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{2cm}|}{Empirical}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{1cm}|}{\textit{IS}}& BLAH \\ \hline
% \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{3cm}|}{\cite{Mukthar_2011}}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{2cm}|}{Empirical}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{1cm}|}{\textit{IS}}& BLAH \\ \hline
% \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{3cm}|}{\cite{Ruan_2011}}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{2cm}|}{Empirical}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{1cm}|}{\textit{IS}}& BLAH \\ \hline
% \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{3cm}|}{\cite{Bohl_2011}}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{2cm}|}{Empirical}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{1cm}|}{\textit{IS}}& BLAH \\ \hline


\bottomrule

\end{xltabular}

\begin{tablenotes}
\footnotesize
\item \textit{CS} represents \cite{RN124}'s \textit{Component Share}, \textit{IS} represents \cite{RN27}'s \textit{Information Share}, while \textit{ILS} represents \cite{Putni__2013,RN16}'s \textit{Information Leadership Share} metric for measuring price discovery.
\end{tablenotes}

\end{threeparttable}

\end{table}
```

Comment: `threeparttablex` which is intended to be used with `longtble` or related multiple page tables wuch as `xltabular` has a different syntax than `threeparttable`, which you used in your example. You can find an example for the use of `threeparttablex` here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/536186/134144

Comment: Apart from that, you can't place a `xltabular` environment inside of a `table` environment if you want the table to correctly span multiple pages.

Comment: @leandriis - thanks. I will check this out now.

Comment: Since you mention fixed width columns: Is there a special reason for which you want to fix the width of, for example, the second and third column? As far as I can tell, the entries in these columns are rather short, so regular `l` (or`c`)  columns should do fine?

Comment: @leandriis - My initial concern was the have the text "BLAH" in the fourth column wrap around multiple lines. This text will be the longest of any of the columns but I couldnt find a way for it to stay within the column unless I used tabularx.

Will longtable enable the columns to be as wide as they need and the row height to expand as needed (assuming I have longtable{\linewidth})?

Comment: You can use xltabular as follows: `\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{lllX}`. With this, the first three columns will be as wide as the widest entry, while the last column fills the available space until the table is as wide as the textwidth while at the same time allowing linebreaks inside the fourth column.

Comment: Hi @leandriis, 
I am trying with your example here (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/536186/134144). As you can see from my code, I only have one set of headers. When I make the column that includes {"What is your household's approximate total annual income..} longer ie I just duplicate some of the results there to try and push the table into a second page, all the happens is that the first page of the document becomes the' continued' page, and then moves then places another header on the second page. Why doesn't the second page continue with any left over data from the first page?

Comment: What do you try to obtain with the definition of the `s` column type (`\hsize=0.3\hsize`)? There's a syntax error.

Comment: Thanks @Bernard - I have fixed that now too using \begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{lllX}. I am still running into the length issue on my table. any ideas?

Comment: I can have plenty of ideas, but I'd like to understand what you'd like to obtain *in fine*.

Comment: @Bernard I think what I'm after: threeparttable as i have footnotes, 4 columns (fourth one varible width), ability for the table to cross multilple pages with the same four columns as the heading for the next page. I felt my code was close but the length of my data doesnt extend to the second page, it just keeps filling the first page, and then throws warnings.

Comment: What does `\hsize=0.3\hsize` mean for you, exactly?

Comment: It meant that that column width was to be one third (0.3) of the largest column width. I know reliase this was not only possibly futile and didnt work, I didnt even need it. I followed @Leandriis's option and stuck with {cccX).  I am now on the issue of the length of my data input excedding one page...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest the following layout using `threeparttablex`, `Xltabular` and `booktabs`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{booktabs, caption}

\newcommand{\heading}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{ThreePartTable}
\begin{TableNotes}[flushleft, para]
\footnotesize
\textit{CS} represents \cite{RN124}'s \textit{Component Share}, \textit{IS} represents \cite{RN27}'s \textit{Information Share}, while \textit{ILS} represents \cite{Putni__2013,RN16}'s \textit{Information Leadership Share} metric for measuring price discovery.
\end{TableNotes}
\centering
\small
\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{ll>{\itshape}lX}

\caption{This table outlines the literature around price discovery in Index Futures markets}\label{table_pd_idxfut}\\
\toprule
Study  &  Th./Emp.  &  Metric  &  Key Findings\\
\midrule
\endfirsthead

\caption[]{(continued from previous page)} \\
\toprule
Study  &  Th./Emp.  &  Metric  &  Key Findings\\
\midrule
\endhead

\bottomrule
\multicolumn{4}{r}{\footnotesize to be continued on the next page}
\endfoot

\bottomrule
\insertTableNotes
\endlastfoot

\cite{Martin_1989}           & Empirical & IS & BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH \\ 
\cite{CHUNG_1991}            & Empirical & IS & BLAH \\ 
\cite{Antoniou_1993}         & Empirical & IS & BLAH \\ 
\cite{Gr_nbichler_1994}      & Empirical & IS & BLAH \\ 
\cite{Martikainen_1996}      & Empirical & IS & BLAH \\ 
  \addlinespace
\cite{Antoniou_1996}         & Empirical & IS & BLAH \\ 
\cite{Turkington_1999}       & Empirical & IS & BLAH \\ 
\cite{Chu_1999}              & Empirical & IS & BLAH \\ 
\cite{Tse_1999}              & Empirical & IS & BLAH \\ 
\cite{Booth_1999}            & Empirical & IS & BLAH \\
  \addlinespace 
\cite{Roope_2002}            & Empirical & IS & BLAH \\ 
\cite{Chen_2002}             & Empirical & IS & BLAH \\ 
\cite{Chan_2002}             & Empirical & IS & BLAH \\ 
\cite{Visvikis_2002}         & Empirical & IS & BLAH \\ 
\cite{Lin_2002}              & Empirical & IS & BLAH \\
  \addlinespace 
\cite{Frino_2002}            & Empirical & IS & BLAH \\ 
\cite{Karagiannis_2003}      & Empirical & IS & BLAH \\
\cite{Frino_2003}            & Empirical & IS & BLAH \\
\cite{Chng_2004}             & Empirical & IS & BLAH \\
\cite{Cheng_2004}            & Empirical & IS & BLAH \\
  \addlinespace
\cite{Zhong_2004}            & Empirical & IS & BLAH \\
\cite{Kurov_2003}            & Empirical & IS & BLAH \\
\cite{So_2004}               & Empirical & IS & BLAH \\
\cite{Chng_2004}             & Empirical & IS & BLAH \\
\cite{Hsieh_2004}            & Empirical & IS & BLAH \\
  \addlinespace
\cite{Ates_2005}             & Empirical & IS & BLAH \\
\cite{Spyrou_2005}           & Empirical & IS & BLAH \\ 
\cite{Zhu_2006}              & Empirical & IS & BLAH \\ 
\cite{Nam_2006}              & Empirical & IS & BLAH \\ 
\cite{M__2007}               & Empirical & IS & BLAH \\
  \addlinespace 
\cite{Kavussanos_2008}       & Empirical & IS & BLAH \\ 
\cite{Kurov_2008}            & Empirical & IS & BLAH \\ 
\cite{Kurov_2008}            & Empirical & IS & BLAH \\ 
\cite{Floros_2008}           & Empirical & IS & BLAH \\ 
\cite{Hsieh_2008}            & Empirical & IS & BLAH \\ 
  \addlinespace
\cite{Debasish_2008}         & Empirical & IS & BLAH \\ 
\cite{Swaroop_Debasish_2009} & Empirical & IS & BLAH \\ 
\cite{Chen_2009}             & Empirical & IS & BLAH \\ 
\cite{Schlusche_2009}        & Empirical & IS & BLAH \\ 
\cite{Tao_2009}              & Empirical & IS & BLAH \\
  \addlinespace 
\cite{Varma_2010}            & Empirical & IS & BLAH \\ 
\cite{Wang_2010}             & Empirical & IS & BLAH \\ 
\cite{Jie_Wei_2010}          & Empirical & IS & BLAH \\ 
\cite{Mukthar_2011}          & Empirical & IS & BLAH \\ 
\cite{Ruan_2011}             & Empirical & IS & BLAH \\ 
  \addlinespace
\cite{Bohl_2011}             & Empirical & IS & BLAH
\end{xltabular}

\end{ThreePartTable}

\end{document}
```

---

For a landscape oriwnted table, add the `pdflscape` package to your premamble and place the whole `ThreePartTable` environment inside of a `landscape` environment. The width of the table automatically adjusts to the avialable space.

Since overleaf uses and older version of `xltabular`, the caption on the second page will show the wrong number. In order to overcome this, you can add `\addtocounter{table}{-1}` as shown in the following example. With an up to date installation and the most recent version of `xltabular`, this line is not neccessary any more:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{booktabs, caption}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\newcommand{\heading}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{ThreePartTable}
\begin{TableNotes}[flushleft, para]
\footnotesize
\textit{CS} represents \cite{RN124}'s \textit{Component Share}, \textit{IS} represents \cite{RN27}'s \textit{Information Share}, while \textit{ILS} represents \cite{Putni__2013,RN16}'s \textit{Information Leadership Share} metric for measuring price discovery.
\end{TableNotes}
\centering
\small
\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{ll>{\itshape}lX}

\caption{This table outlines the literature around price discovery in Index Futures markets}\label{table_pd_idxfut}\addtocounter{table}{-1}\\
\toprule
Study  &  Th./Emp.  &  Metric  &  Key Findings\\
\midrule
\endfirsthead

\caption[]{(continued from previous page)} \\
\toprule
Study  &  Th./Emp.  &  Metric  &  Key Findings\\
\midrule
\endhead

\bottomrule
\multicolumn{4}{r}{\footnotesize to be continued on the next page}
\endfoot

\bottomrule
\insertTableNotes
\endlastfoot

\cite{Martin_1989}           & Empirical & IS & BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH \\ 
\cite{CHUNG_1991}            & Empirical & IS & BLAH \\ 
\cite{Antoniou_1993}         & Empirical & IS & BLAH \\ 
\cite{Gr_nbichler_1994}      & Empirical & IS & BLAH \\ 
\cite{Martikainen_1996}      & Empirical & IS & BLAH \\ 
  \addlinespace
\cite{Antoniou_1996}         & Empirical & IS & BLAH \\ 
\cite{Turkington_1999}       & Empirical & IS & BLAH \\ 
\cite{Chu_1999}              & Empirical & IS & BLAH \\ 
\cite{Tse_1999}              & Empirical & IS & BLAH \\ 
\cite{Booth_1999}            & Empirical & IS & BLAH \\
  \addlinespace 
\cite{Roope_2002}            & Empirical & IS & BLAH \\ 
\cite{Chen_2002}             & Empirical & IS & BLAH \\ 
\cite{Chan_2002}             & Empirical & IS & BLAH \\ 
\cite{Visvikis_2002}         & Empirical & IS & BLAH \\ 
\cite{Lin_2002}              & Empirical & IS & BLAH \\
  \addlinespace 
\cite{Frino_2002}            & Empirical & IS & BLAH \\ 
\cite{Karagiannis_2003}      & Empirical & IS & BLAH \\
\cite{Frino_2003}            & Empirical & IS & BLAH \\
\cite{Chng_2004}             & Empirical & IS & BLAH \\
\cite{Cheng_2004}            & Empirical & IS & BLAH \\
  \addlinespace
\cite{Zhong_2004}            & Empirical & IS & BLAH \\
\cite{Kurov_2003}            & Empirical & IS & BLAH \\
\cite{So_2004}               & Empirical & IS & BLAH \\
\cite{Chng_2004}             & Empirical & IS & BLAH \\
\cite{Hsieh_2004}            & Empirical & IS & BLAH \\
  \addlinespace
\cite{Ates_2005}             & Empirical & IS & BLAH \\
\cite{Spyrou_2005}           & Empirical & IS & BLAH \\ 
\cite{Zhu_2006}              & Empirical & IS & BLAH \\ 
\cite{Nam_2006}              & Empirical & IS & BLAH \\ 
\cite{M__2007}               & Empirical & IS & BLAH \\
  \addlinespace 
\cite{Kavussanos_2008}       & Empirical & IS & BLAH \\ 
\cite{Kurov_2008}            & Empirical & IS & BLAH \\ 
\cite{Kurov_2008}            & Empirical & IS & BLAH \\ 
\cite{Floros_2008}           & Empirical & IS & BLAH \\ 
\cite{Hsieh_2008}            & Empirical & IS & BLAH \\ 
  \addlinespace
\cite{Debasish_2008}         & Empirical & IS & BLAH \\ 
\cite{Swaroop_Debasish_2009} & Empirical & IS & BLAH \\ 
\cite{Chen_2009}             & Empirical & IS & BLAH \\ 
\cite{Schlusche_2009}        & Empirical & IS & BLAH \\ 
\cite{Tao_2009}              & Empirical & IS & BLAH \\
  \addlinespace 
\cite{Varma_2010}            & Empirical & IS & BLAH \\ 
\cite{Wang_2010}             & Empirical & IS & BLAH \\ 
\cite{Jie_Wei_2010}          & Empirical & IS & BLAH \\ 
\cite{Mukthar_2011}          & Empirical & IS & BLAH \\ 
\cite{Ruan_2011}             & Empirical & IS & BLAH \\ 
  \addlinespace
\cite{Bohl_2011}             & Empirical & IS & BLAH
\end{xltabular}

\end{ThreePartTable}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you @leandriis, greatly appreciated.

Comment: this works very well - cheers.

Comment: Hi @leandriis, this works well, however unlike your example, the table number in my version increases/changes from Table 1.1 to Table 1.2 across pages. I am guessing this has to do with some of the features in the cls/bst files specific to my template? Do you know what I should be looking to change in order for the same table number to exist for the same table even if it extends into two pages? Thanks

Comment: Which version of the `xltabular` package did ou use? If I remeber correctly, older version of `xltabular` showed this behaviour. According to the [release notes](https://ctan.org/ctan-ann/id/mailman.2182.1592301853.3866.ctan-ann@ctan.org) of version `0.2d`, this bug was fixed  in this version.

Comment: Thanks - sorry I'm really quite new to this is if that isn't obvious. I am using overleaf to compile but not sure what version of xltabular I'm on. How would I check? Also, is there a simple way of turning that table landscape?

Comment: Overleaf definitely uses an older version. I will extend my answer later to cover this issue as well as the rotation to a landscape orientation.

Comment: Thank you very much - this is phenomenal.

Comment: I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: I can't thank you enough. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is enough to respect the syntax from `threeparttablex`, which is  not exactly that of `threeparttable`:

- the environment is `ThreePartTable` (with 3 capital letters);
- The table notes are *declared* in a `TableNotes` environment at the very beginning of ThreePartTable, then inserted in the longtable (or xltabular) where you please with the `\insertTableNotes` command. In the code that follows,I've inserted it at the very end of the table, in the `\endlastfoot` section.

This being said, I don't understand why you declare fixed width columns, tthese in each cell, use systematically `\multicolumn{1}{m{some length}}{...}`.

Any way, here is a code that works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{booktabs, caption}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{b}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{s}{>{\centering\arraybackslash\hsize=.3\hsize}X}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{3cm}}
\newcommand{\heading}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{ThreePartTable}
\begin{TableNotes}[flushleft, para]
\footnotesize
\textit{CS} represents \cite{RN124}'s \textit{Component Share}, \textit{IS} represents \cite{RN27}'s \textit{Information Share}, while \textit{ILS} represents \cite{Putni__2013,RN16}'s \textit{Information Leadership Share} metric for measuring price discovery.
\end{TableNotes}
\centering
\small
\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{s|s|s|b}

\caption{This table outlines the literature around price discovery in Index Futures markets}\label{table_pd_idxfut}\\
\toprule

\heading{Study} & \heading{Th./Emp.} & \heading{Metric} & \heading{Key Findings}\\
\midrule\midrule
\endfirsthead
%
\multicolumn{4}{r}{\footnotesize to be continued}
\endfoot
\captionsetup{labelsep=space}
\caption[]{(continued from previous page)} \\\hline
\heading{Study} & \heading{Th./Emp.} & \heading{Metric} & \heading{Key Findings}\\
\endhead
%
\bottomrule
\insertTableNotes
\endlastfoot

\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{3cm}|}{\cite{Martin_1989}}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{2cm}|}{Empirical}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{1cm}|}{\textit{IS}}& BLAH \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{3cm}|}{\cite{CHUNG_1991}}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{2cm}|}{Empirical}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{1cm}|}{\textit{IS}}& BLAH \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{3cm}|}{\cite{Antoniou_1993}}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{2cm}|}{Empirical}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{1cm}|}{\textit{IS}}& BLAH \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{3cm}|}{\cite{Gr_nbichler_1994}}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{2cm}|}{Empirical}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{1cm}|}{\textit{IS}}& BLAH \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{3cm}|}{\cite{Martikainen_1996}}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{2cm}|}{Empirical}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{1cm}|}{\textit{IS}}& BLAH \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{3cm}|}{\cite{Antoniou_1996}}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{2cm}|}{Empirical}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{1cm}|}{\textit{IS}}& BLAH \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{3cm}|}{\cite{Turkington_1999}}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{2cm}|}{Empirical}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{1cm}|}{\textit{IS}}& BLAH \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{3cm}|}{\cite{Chu_1999}}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{2cm}|}{Empirical}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{1cm}|}{\textit{IS}}& BLAH \\ \hline
%
 \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{3cm}|}{\cite{Tse_1999}}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{2cm}|}{Empirical}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{1cm}|}{\textit{IS}}& BLAH \\ \hline
%
\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{3cm}|}{\cite{Booth_1999}}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{2cm}|}{Empirical}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{1cm}|}{\textit{IS}}& BLAH \\ \hline
%
\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{3cm}|}{\cite{Roope_2002}}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{2cm}|}{Empirical}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{1cm}|}{\textit{IS}}& BLAH \\ \hline
%
\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{3cm}|}{\cite{Chen_2002}}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{2cm}|}{Empirical}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{1cm}|}{\textit{IS}}& BLAH \\ \hline
%
\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{3cm}|}{\cite{Chan_2002}}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{2cm}|}{Empirical}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{1cm}|}{\textit{IS}}& BLAH \\ \hline
%
\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{3cm}|}{\cite{Visvikis_2002}}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{2cm}|}{Empirical}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{1cm}|}{\textit{IS}}& BLAH \\ \hline
%
\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{3cm}|}{\cite{Lin_2002}}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{2cm}|}{Empirical}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{1cm}|}{\textit{IS}}& BLAH \\ \hline
%
\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{3cm}|}{\cite{Frino_2002}}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{2cm}|}{Empirical}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{1cm}|}{\textit{IS}}& BLAH \\ \hline
%
 \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{3cm}|}{\cite{Karagiannis_2003}}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{2cm}|}{Empirical}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{1cm}|}{\textit{IS}}& BLAH \\ \hline
%
\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{3cm}|}{\cite{Frino_2003}}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{2cm}|}{Empirical}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{1cm}|}{\textit{IS}}& BLAH \\ \hline
%
\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{3cm}|}{\cite{Chng_2004}}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{2cm}|}{Empirical}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{1cm}|}{\textit{IS}}& BLAH \\ \hline
%
\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{3cm}|}{\cite{Cheng_2004}}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{2cm}|}{Empirical}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{1cm}|}{\textit{IS}}& BLAH \\ \hline
%
 \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{3cm}|}{\cite{Zhong_2004}}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{2cm}|}{Empirical}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{1cm}|}{\textit{IS}}& BLAH \\ \hline
%
\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{3cm}|}{\cite{Kurov_2003}}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{2cm}|}{Empirical}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{1cm}|}{\textit{IS}}& BLAH \\ \hline
% \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{3cm}|}{\cite{So_2004}}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{2cm}|}{Empirical}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{1cm}|}{\textit{IS}}& BLAH \\ \hline
% \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{3cm}|}{\cite{Chng_2004}}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{2cm}|}{Empirical}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{1cm}|}{\textit{IS}}& BLAH \\ \hline
% \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{3cm}|}{\cite{Hsieh_2004}}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{2cm}|}{Empirical}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{1cm}|}{\textit{IS}}& BLAH \\ \hline
% \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{3cm}|}{\cite{Ates_2005}}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{2cm}|}{Empirical}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{1cm}|}{\textit{IS}}& BLAH \\ \hline
%
\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{3cm}|}{\cite{Spyrou_2005}}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{2cm}|}{Empirical}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{1cm}|}{\textit{IS}}& BLAH \\ \hline
%
 \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{3cm}|}{\cite{Zhu_2006}}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{2cm}|}{Empirical}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{1cm}|}{\textit{IS}}& BLAH \\ \hline
%
\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{3cm}|}{\cite{Nam_2006}}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{2cm}|}{Empirical}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{1cm}|}{\textit{IS}}& BLAH \\ \hline
%
\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{3cm}|}{\cite{M__2007}}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{2cm}|}{Empirical}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{1cm}|}{\textit{IS}}& BLAH \\ \hline
%
\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{3cm}|}{\cite{Kavussanos_2008}}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{2cm}|}{Empirical}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{1cm}|}{\textit{IS}}& BLAH \\ \hline
%
\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{3cm}|}{\cite{Kurov_2008}}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{2cm}|}{Empirical}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{1cm}|}{\textit{IS}}& BLAH \\ \hline
%
\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{3cm}|}{\cite{Kurov_2008}}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{2cm}|}{Empirical}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{1cm}|}{\textit{IS}}& BLAH \\ \hline
%
\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{3cm}|}{\cite{Floros_2008}}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{2cm}|}{Empirical}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{1cm}|}{\textit{IS}}& BLAH \\ \hline
%
\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{3cm}|}{\cite{Hsieh_2008}}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{2cm}|}{Empirical}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{1cm}|}{\textit{IS}}& BLAH \\ \hline
%
\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{3cm}|}{\cite{Debasish_2008}}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{2cm}|}{Empirical}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{1cm}|}{\textit{IS}}& BLAH \\ \hline
%
\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{3cm}|}{\cite{Swaroop_Debasish_2009}}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{2cm}|}{Empirical}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{1cm}|}{\textit{IS}}& BLAH \\ \hline
%
 \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{3cm}|}{\cite{Chen_2009}}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{2cm}|}{Empirical}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{1cm}|}{\textit{IS}}& BLAH \\ \hline
%
\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{3cm}|}{\cite{Schlusche_2009}}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{2cm}|}{Empirical}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{1cm}|}{\textit{IS}}& BLAH \\ \hline
%
\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{3cm}|}{\cite{Tao_2009}}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{2cm}|}{Empirical}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{1cm}|}{\textit{IS}}& BLAH \\ \hline
%
\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{3cm}|}{\cite{Varma_2010}}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{2cm}|}{Empirical}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{1cm}|}{\textit{IS}}& BLAH \\ \hline
%
\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{3cm}|}{\cite{Wang_2010}}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{2cm}|}{Empirical}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{1cm}|}{\textit{IS}}& BLAH \\ \hline
%
\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{3cm}|}{\cite{Jie_Wei_2010}}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{2cm}|}{Empirical}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{1cm}|}{\textit{IS}}& BLAH \\ \hline
%
\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{3cm}|}{\cite{Mukthar_2011}}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{2cm}|}{Empirical}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{1cm}|}{\textit{IS}}& BLAH \\ \hline
%
\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{3cm}|}{\cite{Ruan_2011}}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{2cm}|}{Empirical}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{1cm}|}{\textit{IS}}& BLAH \\ \hline
%
\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{3cm}|}{\cite{Bohl_2011}}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{2cm}|}{Empirical}&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{1cm}|}{\textit{IS}}& BLAH
\end{xltabular}

\end{ThreePartTable}

\end{document}
```

*Addendum*: If you want 3 standard X columns and a 4th X column three times less wide, you have to use the syntax in the table preamble:

```
 *{3}{>{\hsize=1.2\hsize}X}>{\hsize=0.4\hsize}X
```

(Namely, the coefficients have to be proportional to the relative  column width, and their sum has to be equal to the number of X columns).

[image]

[image]

Comment: thanks for your help with this - much appreciated. I will check this now.

Comment: I will no longer fixed the width of the columns - @Bernard

Comment: In this case, replace xltabular with a  simple longtable ad change the table preamble accordingly. The rest doesn't change.

Comment: Thank you very much @Bernard!